# Estimate change in total cost if cost is given by $C(q)=3q^2+5q+10$

Tags: calculus

Suppose the total cost in dollars of manufacturing q units of a certain commodity is $C(q)=3q^2+5q+10$. If the current level of production is 40 units, estimate how the total cost will change if 40.5 units are produced.

Answer (score 2):

The current cost is $C(40)$ while the projected cost is $C(40.5)$, so the (estimated) change in total cost is $$C(40.5)-C(40).$$

(So we compute $C(q)$ for $q=40$ and $q=40.5$ and insert it into the above equation.)

Or if you want to represent it as a proportion of the current cost: $$\frac{C(40.5)-C(40)}{C(40)} \times 100\%.$$

Comment: so you would plug in 50 for q?

Comment: 50?  The question asks for 40.  But, yes, we plug in 40 to get C(40) and also plug in 40.5 to get C(40.5), then take the difference: C(40.5)-C(40) --- this is how much the total cost would change.

Answer (score 2):

A calculus-based approach is to make the linear approximation $\Delta C \approx C'(q)\Delta q$ where $C'(q)=6q+5$. Then the change in going from $q=40$ to $40.5$ can be estimated as $\Delta C \approx C'(40)(40.5-40).$ This gives approximately same result (about one unit different) as computing $\Delta C$ directly as in Rebecca's answer.